# IOException in EJB3

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ioexception

So I kind of asked this question before but I didn't get quiet what i needed. I am new with JAVA entreprise editon and EJB3 and i am using it to create a  Session bean on a JBOSS server v4.0. So here is my exact problem my buisness method on the bean must creates a file save on it some String sent by the client, so i am obliged to throw an IOExcpetion. I tried a Hello world with EJB3 and it worked but the moment i start to use Exceptions on my bean my client no longer conncts the server bean. i will give you the code of my bean and my client and the error i get and can someone please help me because i kind of tried everthing i could and still the same error, it is an engineering projet and i am really runnig out of time,still only two weeks to go :(
My session Bean code
    package com.et;

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import com.gestionfichier.gestion.GestionFichier;

@Stateless
public class EnvoiCodeExceptionBean implements EnvoiCodeException {

public String EnvoiCode(String Code) throws IOException 
{
    PrintWriter ecrivain = null;
    File f=GestionFichier.CreerFichier("temp");
    ecrivain =  new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f)));
    ecrivain.println(Code);
    ecrivain.close();
    throw new IOException("error");


}
    }
```

My client code

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.naming.Context;
 import javax.naming.InitialContext;
 import javax.naming.NamingException;

 import com.et.EnvoiCodeException;
 public class AppelClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
 Context context = new InitialContext();
 EnvoiCodeException beanRemote = (EnvoiCodeException)
 context.lookup("EnvoiCodeExceptionBean/remote");
 beanRemote.EnvoiCode("some Sring to send");

 } catch (NamingException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
  }
```

and what i get on my Eclipse Console

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at $Proxy0.EnvoiCode(Unknown Source)
at AppelClient.main(AppelClient.java:14)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at    org.jboss.remoting.loading.RemotingClassLoader.loadClass(RemotingClassLoader.java:50)
at org.jboss.remoting.loading.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:139)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:913)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:913)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:913)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:913)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObject(JavaSerializationManager.java:128)
at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableUnMarshaller.read(SerializableUnMarshaller.java:66)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.transport(SocketClientInvoker.java:279)
at org.jboss.remoting.RemoteClientInvoker.invoke(RemoteClientInvoker.java:143)
at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:525)
at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:488)
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:55)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.aspects.security.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:77)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at    org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessRemoteProxy.invoke(StatelessRemoteProxy.java:102)
... 2 more
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I think it is wrong anyway. Read the documentation on [UndeclaredThrowable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException.html). Do you know if the request receives your server (log it)?

Comment: I read the documentation and the EJB restrictions and i think that EJB does not handle the use of IOExceptions and the use of files in a Bean for some security reasons so it launched an exception that was not thrown by my bean. So it seems that using EJB3 for this kind of projet is a hopeless case. Any solutions something like interceptors to handle these exceptions because i really dont have time to swith and learn something else

Comment: Why do you explicitly throw IOException in any case? That seems pointless. If you want to return the exception and you believe the user can handle it, you could catch the IOException and throw a more relevant exception with details.

Answer (score -1):

This Exception might be thrown from the API you have used (GestionFichier).
As it seems it is some User modified Exception thrown. So it was not handled properly.
Please check and Catch Throwable and try it again. It may help you to get better idea about Exception been generated here.

Comment: Please do not catch Throwable, ever.

Comment: Perhaps just catch Exception then.

Comment: yes very true, i agree as I wrote the way was may be wrong, thanks to clarify.

Comment: And ya if I still catch Throwable will  show the Exception/Error. java is providing it. We can catch it but may be it is not suggested way

Comment: my API "CreerFichier" has a try catch bloc in which i use createNewFile from java.io.file and i catch an IOException i can't see what is wrong with that i user in other projects and i worked only EJB3 give me this error (sorry for being so late)

Comment: Add the Catch Exception below the IOException and try to check which other exception is coming. as It seems some other Unexpected Exception is coming which is not handled or caught by catch.